# Kafka Streams: re-key KTable by two or more foreign keys

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

Assume a (simplified) class `A` like this:

```java
class A {
  private Long id;
  private String someContent;
  private Long fk1;
  private Long fk2;
  // Getters and setters accordingly
}
```

Both `fk1` and `fk2` point to the PK of another entity (not shown for brevity, of no relevance to the question).

Now assume a Kafka topic built from instances of class `A`, keyed by its `id`.

Ingesting the topic into a Kafka Streams application, how can I re-key the resulting `KTable<Long, A>` by both `fk1` and `fk2`? Note that the resulting key should **not** be changed or turned into some kind of composite key as it is used in later join operations.

My (naive) solution involves creating two `KTable`s from the input stream, re-keying them by `fk1` and `fk2` accordingly and then outer joining both resulting (re-keyed) `KTable`s.

```java
KStream<Long, A> in = streamsBuilder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(...));

KTable<Long, A> rekeyedByFk1 = in
    .toTable()
    .groupBy(
        (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value.fk1(), value),
        Grouped.with(...))
    .aggregate(
        Aggregate::new,
        (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.add(value),
        (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.remove(value),
        Materialized.with(...));

KTable<Long, a> rekeyedByFk2 = in
    .toTable()
    .groupBy(
        (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value.fk2(), value),
        Grouped.with(...))
    .aggregate(
        ... same as above
    );

KTable<Long, A> joined = rekeyedByFk1
    .outerJoin(
        rekeyedByFk2,
        <value joiner>)
    .groupBy(KeyValue::pair, Grouped.with(...)).aggregate(...);
```

`<value joiner>` would integrate the (already pre-joined) `Aggregate`s as to avoid duplicates.

Does this seem like a viable solution, or are there better / simpler / more efficient implementations?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to re-key at all. Kafka Streams natively supports FK-table-table joins, so you can just do:

```java
KTable<Long, A> in = streamsBuilder.table(...);

// both fk-tables
KTable<Long, B> t1 = streamsBuilder.table(...);    
KTable<Long, C> t2 = streamsBuilder.table(...);

KTable<Long, AEnriched> result =
    in.join(t1, (k,v) -> v.fk1,...)
      .join(t2, (k,v) -> v.fk2,...);
```

Note the "ForeignKeyExtractor" function that tell Kafka Streams which left-table value attribute should be used as FK to do the lookup into the right-hand table.

There is also a nice tutorial about FK-table-table joins: https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/foreign-key-joins/kstreams.html

Kafka Streams will do all the required co-partitioning internally for you. For details how this is implemented, in case you are interested, check out https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-enrichment-with-kafka-streams-foreign-key-joins/

Comment: Thanks for clarification. FK-table-table joins are out of the play as the use case is as follows: a Folder entity (A) may have a Person entity attached as either a customer or a billing address (or both), both identified by the FK. In order to build a Person aggregate containing all associated Folder entities (regardless via which 'role'), I'd need to build an appropriate list of Folders, eliminating duplicates, and finally attach that Folder list to the Person entity...

Comment: If I understand correctly, to build up a `Person` result, you could do a final `enrichedFolderTable.groupBy((k,v) -> v.personId).aggregate(...)` on the result of the second FK join?